# PHP Session Variable from URL

Tags: php, session, mobile

I'm not familiar with PHP session variables or how they work exactly, but I'm working on a site that has a mobile counterpart. On the mobile site (developed by another company)there's a link to go to the full site that uses a URL ending in '?mobile=false', and I'm just wondering how I can use that to allow mobile users to access the full site?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by _'how I can use that to allow mobile users to access the full site?'_? What is 'access'?

Comment: Access as in the ability to view the full site by clicking a link within the mobile site.

Comment: Are those two different sites? Or is it the same site using a different template?

Comment: It's two different sites - using the code you suggested has done the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something like this in your entry point:

```
if (isset($_GET['mobile']) && $_GET['mobile'] == 'false')
{
    session_start(); // If you haven't done so already
    $_SESSION['ShowFullSite'] = true;
}
```

Then you can check for `$_SESSION['ShowFullSite']` afterwards, which will be set as long as the session lives.

Answer (score 1):

You can access this URI part with $_GET['mobile'] where this will hold false then. And btw. this is not a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think you shoould use the Cookies like annother development, not Session.  [Click Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the parameter using $_GET['mobile'] in the first page and set the session variable in that page and you use it in other pages.
To set the session you need to start the session first.
session_start();
Then to set
$_SESSION['mobile']=false;
You can check in pages by 
if($_SESSION['mobile']){
}
To clear session you can use
session_unset();

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you have two different sites, then if you want to redirect your users, you have to add something like this in the index of your mobile site:

```
  if (isset($_GET['mobile']) && $_GET['mobile'] == 'false'))
       header('Location: http://www.myfullsite.com/');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of thing I was looking for!